# Exponentiating 4 by 4 matrix analytically

Tags: matrix-analysis

Does there exist an analytical method by which i can exponentiate a 4 by 4 matrix, in the same way as the general 2 by 2 matrix case in pauli matrix basis. I have dirac matrices (which are composed of direct products of pauli matrices) as my basis for 4 by 4 matrices. 
I need an analytical way !
Any reply is appreciated.
regards

Comment: What is the result you are alluding to for $2\times 2? matrices?

Comment: By "analytically" you mean "explicitely"? Put your matrix $X$ in Jordan form. Then $X=S+N$ where $S$ is diagonal and $N$ nilpotent and $SN=NS$, and $\exp(X)=\exp(S)\cdot\exp(N)$ which is quite explicit to compute...

Comment: @Qfwfq: that is computationally tractable, but NOT explicit (try writing a formula in terms of matrix elements of $X$)

Comment: Also, why all the votes to close?

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps I misunderstand the question.  When you say you have Dirac matrices, does that mean that you are computing the exponential of a liner combination of Dirac matrices?  If so, then there is a very simple analytical formula in any dimension: just use the Clifford relations in the exponential series.

More concretely, suppose that you would like to compute the exponential of a matrix $X := \sum_i x^i \Gamma_i$, where the Dirac matrices $\Gamma_i$ obey the Clifford relation
$$
\Gamma_i \Gamma_j + \Gamma_j \Gamma_i = - 2 g_{ij} I~,
$$
with $I$ the identity matrix.  Then it follows from this relation that
$$
X^2 = - x^2 I~,
$$
where I have introduced the (indefinite, if $g_{ij}$ has indefinite signature) "squared norm"
$$
x^2 = \sum_{i,j} x^i x^j g_{ij}~.
$$

If $x^2$ = 0, then
$$
\exp X = I + X
$$
and if $x^2 \neq 0$, then letting $x = \sqrt{x^2}$ (which could be imaginary),
$$
\exp X = \cos x I + \frac{\sin x}{x} X~.
$$

**Added** (for the "heathens")

Quiaochu's comment is correct.  Here are some more details.

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional real vector space with a non-degenerate inner product $\left<-,-\right>$.  Let $Cl(V)$ be the corresponding Clifford algebra.  Let $\rho: Cl(V) \to \operatorname{End}(M)$ be an irreducible representation of $Cl(V)$.  Let $(e_i)$ be a basis for $V$.  Then $\Gamma_i := \rho(e_i)$ are called *Dirac matrices* of $CL(V)$ in the representation $M$.

Comment: For us heathens: what are Dirac matrices?

Comment: @Igor Rivin: as far as I understand (which is not to say much) the first display (Clifford relation) is sort-of the defintion. 

Comment: @Igor: they are a particular matrix representation of a certain Clifford algebra. 

Answer (score 4):

There is a completely explicit formula in [this paper](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5188175/matrixexp2.pdf) of Bensauod and Mouline (rendicotti Palermo, 2005), which is quite compact  for low dimensions.

Comment: (There seems to be a problem with the link.)

Comment: @Andres: should be fixed now...

Comment: It's explicit in terms of the solution of a differential equation related to the characteristic polynomial.  Of course, to solve that differential equation explicitly you need the eigenvalues...  